# what does "()" in programming mean? As an example: getche() I understand what getche does, but why the () at the end?

Tags: syntax

As an example: getche()   I understand what getche does, but why the () at the end?

If you are not putting anything in the parenthesis, why do you need them to be there?  Just because of standards?

Thanks

Comment: It's a function call without parameters. I think the parser/lexer is easier to build because it distinguishes the function `foo()` from the variable `foo`.

Comment: if I know correctly, the equivalent in Objective-C is done with [] around the expression instead of the typical () at the end, like `ret = [sampleClass max:a andNum2:b];` - just to show that it isn't necessarily (). It's part of the syntax, but it's basically a function call as mentioned above.

Comment: Syntax depends a lot on **what programming language** you use! In some dialects it's a function call, in others a `null` object (Haskell), in general parenthesis are used as a grouping construct.

Answer (score 3):

Whether a function/method call needs to have parentheses at the end is a syntax particularity that varies from language to language.  In Ruby, for example, you don't need it, while in Java, you do.

The compiler can use it to determine that you're making a function/method call.  In many languages, you can reference a function as an object, so you need the parentheses to distinguish a reference to a function from a call to a function.

For example, in javascript:

```
function something(){
   return "hello";
}

var a = something;
var b = something();
```

The variable `a` will contain the actual function `something`, while the variable `b` will contain "hello".

Comment: Also from a perspective of someone new to the code that you have written, it makes it easy to read the code and know that it is a function/method.

Answer (score 0):

It executes the function without passing any parameters.

In languages with first-class functions, `foo` and `foo()` have different meanings. Consider these two examples, in Lua:

```
local bar = foo -- Assigns foo to bar. bar is now the function at foo.

local bar = foo() -- Executes foo, and assigns the return value to bar.
```

This, of course, depends on the language you are using. For example, in Haskell, no parenthesis are used to call functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax for Method/function.
Why is the need of it ? Because in the () you can provide the input arguments as well.

like for example :

```
var sum = addition(3,4);
```

Here addition can be defined as:

```
int addition(int a, int b)
{
  return (a+b);
}
```